# migration script in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

In the Book "MongoDB-Applied Design Patterns" two approaches are given :

first:

```
db.nodes.update(
    {},
{$set: { short_description: '' } }, 
false, // upsert
true // multi
);
```

it can be slow, and it can impact the performance of your application negatively.

"Another option for MongoDB users is to update your application to account for the absence of the new field "

```
def get_node_by_url(url):
node = db.nodes.find_one({'url': url}) 
node.setdefault('short_description', '')
return node
```

Once we have the code in place to handle documents with or without the short_description field, we might choose to gradually migrate the collection in the background, while our application is running

```
def add_short_descriptions(): 
         node_ids_to_migrate = db.nodes.find(
        {'short_description': {'$exists':False}}).limit(100)
        db.nodes.update(
        { '_id': {'$in': node_ids_to_migrate } },
        { '$set': { 'short_description': '' } },
        multi=True)
```

I couldnt understand the second approach ,how is it different from the first one in terms of performance.?

Comment: It differs massively since it's iterating 100 items returned by the cursor in order to get the values to update. You also either have a mistake in your interpretation or the "book" is wrong, since you would only supply the `_id` field from the returned documents to the `$in` argument as an array. The first is basically setting "everything" and does this in one fast request. The second specifically asks for "missing" fields and then sets those "found" to a default value. You ( or book ) are doing it wrong, not only for the statement but also in approach.

Comment: What could be better approach to add the field in the document ?

Comment: Beyond asking for a clarification of the book you are reading it's simply not clear what you are asking to do here. The two "types" of operations are polar opposites. Maybe you should not be citing books and simply asking ( or really searching because your actual question is likely already answered ) what it is you actually want to do here. Which is what?

Comment: Well one thing I can clear up is that the statement in the book ( second one, from page 21 chapter 2 ) which apparently appears exactly how you posted it here is completely incorrect. Pretty horrible book IMHO of a short glance through the contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach only updates 100 documents at a time in the background, instead of all documents at once. You could run the `add_short_descriptions` function in a loop with a half-second sleep in between, for example, in order to limit its load on your system.

I haven't tested the difference between these two approaches, but there's a good chance that the second approach is no longer needed. Rick Copeland's book was written before WiredTiger became MongoDB's default storage engine, so he had to work around concurrency bottlenecks in MongoDB that have now largely been eliminated.

Comment: So , the first approach works fine without affecting the performance ?

Comment: I haven't tested the difference between these two approaches, but there's a good chance that the second approach is no longer needed.